# Cannot convert to JSON Array

Tags: java, php, android, json, web-services

I tried to convert JSON from PHP server side to string in Android.

It force closes with (java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject ) Error.

This is my Web class for HTTP connecting:

```
public class Web {
    public static String readUrl(String url) {
        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost method = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(method);
            InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
            String result = convertInputstreamToString(inputStream);
            return result;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    private static String convertInputstreamToString(InputStream inputStream){
        try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String line ="";
            while ((line = reader.readLine())!=null) {
                builder.append(line);
            }
            return String.valueOf(builder);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is my Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    String result = Web.readUrl("http://192.168.1.53/mana/mana%20records.php");
                    if (result != null) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray records = new JSONArray(result);
                            for (int i = 0; i < records.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject record = records.getJSONObject(i);
                                Log.d("Records", record.getString("date"));
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        thread.start();
    }
}
```

And this is my JSON:

```
[{"date":"2015-12-01","Shift Day":"on","Shift Night":"",
"Shift Person":"a","Code":"1","1st":"1000","Size 8":null,
"2nd":"1","3rd":"10","logo":"1000","Storage":"10000"},
{"date":"2015-12-02","Shift Day":"",
"Shift Night":"on","Shift Person":"b","Code":"2","1st":"2000",
"Size 8":null,"2nd":"2","3rd":"20","logo":"2000",
"Storage":"20000"}]
```

Comment: Do you have a more detailed error?

Comment: And where is php-script which generates json?

Comment: Why don't you try printing out the contents of `result`?

Comment: In printing also have this error

Comment: on which particular line are you getting error. can you show that in code?

Comment: @PankajNimgade ^^^^^^^^^

Comment: I just tryed your code and it is ok. The problem should be somewhere else.
Can you post the full error stacktrace?